# The problem with npm - internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968

Tags: node.js, npm

Good day!
I reinstalled Node.js to the latest version, from the Linux terminal and now npm gives the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

How can you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try `npm install semver` or try to delete existing node_moudles folder and run `npm install` command